# how to read the url and check for HTTPS in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, security, https

How to read the URL and check for HTTPS in python?

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
html = response.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Even if its giving error, try to install following and try again the above code:

```
pip install urllib3
```